# Windows 10 blue screen and repair loop caused by minitool parition wizard when resizing C partition

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, bsod, bootrepair

I have a critical problem here.
I will try to simply explain what happened.
I used Minitool Partition Wizard to shrink D: partition and extend C: Partition at the same time.
I got a choice as shown in the image to "restart the PC and minitool partition wizard will automatically finish rest of the pending jobs".
[my choice in minitool parition wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBLaK.png)

The Current Behaviour:
windows is stuck in this cycle/loop

- minitool partition wizard tries to execute the resize operation then windows blue screen appears for few seconds.
- windows then restarts and reapir screen appears.

I need your help
**I need a command in cmd to revent/stop/remove the operation/process of minitool partition wizard that runs before windows startup**

I tried a lot of things in the repair screen, i tried as in the image:
4) Enable Safe Mode.
7) Disable driver signature enforcement.
8) Disable early launch anti-malware protection.
9) disable automatic restart after failure.

[my tries to repair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1svT.png)

Comment: I would try an offine USB boot disc like Hirens or Medicat.  This would allow you to work on the problem without being interrupted with crashes, reboots etc.  Inspect the BSOD dump for clues, look at the RUN/RUNONCE registry keys, rename the partition wizard .exe so it doesn't run next boot, set "AutoReboot" to 0 in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl to disable automatic rebooting upon BSOD, try a different offline partitioning tool, email minitool support, etc.  Are the C and D partitions on the same physical drive or separate drives?

Comment: The safest is to revert to a previous disk image. Boot from USB and restore the image made before attempting a major change to the disk structure.

Comment: Did you try the Cancel option in the Minitool dialog?